# Android OpenCV - no .so files in /lib directories

Tags: android, opencv

I have spent days at this point compiling and re-compiling different versions of OpenCV to be used in Android apps.

I don't get any compiler errors, and I'm following all the steps in the tutorials.

But no .so files are getting generated and being placed in the /lib folder

Any ideas?

Comment: I've managed to put it to run on Android. But in order to help you I will need to check my sources again.

Comment: Is it possible for me to just download the libraries and put them in the lib/ folder?  Why do I have to compile the thing myself?

Answer (score 0):

Do you work with eclipse? Which /lib folder do you mean?

1. the android/android-opencv/libs folder or
2. a specific folder from the included samples e.g. android/apps/CVCamera/libs folder?

Did you build OpenCV AND android-opencv AND the specific project without errors? You should check this first.

For a first shot I would suggest you to build a project from the included samples (e.g. the "CVCamera" project). In my folder structure it looked like this:

1. $cd somepath/OpenCV-2.3.0/android/apps/CVCamera
2. $sh project_create.sh
3. $ant compile

If this does not work then follow the error messages or post them here. Perhaps I can help you.

Good luck,
gartenabfall